# Daily FTP backup script for external hard drive

Tags: macos, backup, imac, ftp

I need to set a daily backup of a specific external hard drive in iMac to a FTP server. In Windows I use a batch file but with OS X I'm a little lost.

Comment: In OS X you would use a shell script. If you have a batch file you would use on Windows, paste it into your question and perhaps someone can translate the functionality 

Comment: Thanks @forquare but i will use software, will try gbcopy or ffort do you know any of these?

Answer (score 1):

You may write this script and it will work for not big number of files, but entire external hard drive backup to ftp server only using bash is a hard task. Because of possible connection problem, because of namespace problem. (Some file names on Mac ) may be impossible to store on your ftp server. If you backup small number of files ~100mb just zip them and upload with sh ftp command. But if the amount of data is large >1gb it is better to use third party software like "immortal files" or "goodsync".